# How to submit a form in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I feel crazy asking this question here, but I can't find **any** good tutorials for how to submit a form and capture the data for RN.  Everything I do find is someone pushing a library *"just npm install react-native-form-genie-magic-box and call it in your project*"...

but I just want to know - How to submit a form in vanilla **React Native**.

Sample code:
**AuthContainer**

```
class AuthContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const {  errorMessage, handleLogin } = this.props
    return (
     <Login
       errorMessage={errorMessage}
       onLoginClick={(e) => handleLogin(e)}
     />
    )
  }
}
.....

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleLogin: (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const form = e.target
      const data = serialize(form, {hash: true})
      const creds = { email:data.email, password: data.password }
      dispatch(loginUser(creds))
    },
  }
}
```

**Login**

```
import { Container, Content, Form, Item, Input, Label, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
....
const Login = ({errorMessage, onLoginClick}) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <Form >
          {errorMessage &&
           <Text>{errorMessage}</Text>
          }
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Email</Label>
            <Input
              type="email"
              name="email"
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel last>
            <Label>Password</Label>
            <Input secureTextEntry={true} />
          </Item>
          <Button onPress={onLoginClick} ><Text>Sign in</Text></Button>
        </Form>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

**Question:**  How can I just capture the submitted email and password in AuthContainer's `handleLogin` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `<input` you need to add something like this, example:

```
<Input onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})} value={this.state.username}
```

And when you use the `onPress` function you just need to get the this.state.username and use it when you want.
I don't usually do a function that handle the `Login` or something in other `.js` so you need to pass the `this.state.username` to the `page` that handles it.

What i usually do if I really need to pass something to other `page` is using `GLOBALS`, example:

```
// globals.js 
module.exports = {
  username: '',
};
```

And then to use the `globals.js`

```
// import the globals.js
GLOBAL = require('./globals');

<Input onChangeText={(text) => this_onButtonPressed(text) value={this.state.username}/>

_onButtonPressed(text){
  GLOBAL.username = this.state.username
  // call function that handles it
}
```

And then on the `page` that handles it you need to `import` it again and just use GLOBAL.username.

If you didn't understand it tell me I will try to explain it better, I need to know if you want to handle the `login` on a different `.js` or it can be on the `.js` that has the Form (its easier like this)

Comment: Ah interesting. So the approach in RN is to just use controlled inputs 100%, where you save the values from the inputs after each change, and pressing the button just calls some function that does something with that data. I was going for an uncontrolled input approach, but this will work. Thanks for the good answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following url for form implementation in react.
https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form/issues/383